# Matlab Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test

Tags: matlab, exponential, cdf, goodness-of-fit

I'm using MATLAB to analyze some neuroscience data, and I made an interspike interval distribution and fit an exponential to it. Then, I wanted to check this fit using a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with MATLAB.

The data for the neuron spikes is just stored in a vector of spikes. The `spikes` vector is a 111 by 1 vector, where each entry is another vector. Each entry in thie `spikes` vector represents a trial. The number of spikes in each trial varies. For example, `spikes{1}` is a `[1x116 double]`, meaning there are 116 spikes. The next has 115 spikes, then 108, etc.

Now, I understand that the kstest in MATLAB takes a couple of parameters. You enter the data in the first one, so I took all the interspike intervals and created a row vector `alldiffs` which stores all the interspike intervals. I want to set my CDF to that for an exponential function fit:

```
test_cdf = [transpose(alldiffs), transpose(1-exp(-alldiffs*firingrate))];
```

Note that the theoretical exponential (with which I fit the data) is `r*exp(-rt)` where `r` is the firing rate. I get a firing rate of about 0.2. Now, when I put this all together, I run the kstest:

```
[h,p] = kstest(alldiffs, 'CDF', test_cdf)
```

However, the result is a p value on the order of `1.4455e-126`. I've tried redoing the `test_cdf` with another of the methods on Mathworks' website documentation:

```
test_cdf = [transpose(alldiffs), cdf('exp', transpose(alldiffs), 1/firingrate)];
```

This gives the exact same result! Is the fit just horrible? I don't know why I get such low p-values. Please help!

I would post an image of the fit, but I don't have enough reputation.

P.S. If there is a better place to post this, let me know and I'll repost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with fake data and yet another way to create the CDF:

```
>> data = exprnd(.2, 100);
>> test_cdf = makedist('exp', 'mu', .2);
>> [h, p] = kstest(data, 'CDF', test_cdf)

h =

     0


p =

    0.3418
```

However, why are you doing a KS Test?

> All models are wrong, some are useful.

No neuron is *perfectly* a Poisson process and with enough data, you'll always have a significantly non-exponential ISI, as measured by a KS test. That doesn't mean you can't make the simplifying assumption of an exponential ISI, depending on what phenomena you're trying model.

Comment: Thanks! I see what you're saying. I was using the KS test as a way to look at different neurons and see if they differ significantly in how close the IID resembles an exponential (or how close to a Poisson process the neuron firing is), but that makes sense. Perhaps I need a less sensitive test, or maybe I can just use the p-value from the KS test to compare.

Comment: Hi @nick consider using the Fano factor.